# activerecord and timezones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, timezone, rails-activerecord

Here's the situation.  We have a rails 3.2 app running on heroku, and developers all over the world.  We want to standardise on UTC for everything.  Our team speaks UTC even among ourselves (eg. when planning meeting times).  We want the app to do the same.  We can convert things back into people's local timezones for display at some later point.

The problem is that when I save something into the database (for instance, creating a new post in the forums) it thinks that my local time (as reported by my computer) is UTC, and saves it as such.

For example, it's lunchtime on Thursday 14th February here in sunny Melbourne, Australia (UTC+11).  I make a new post, then look in the console:

```
1.9.3p194 :009 > p = Post.first
 => #<Post id: 12, author_id: 1, subject: "Another post ", body: "a very recent one!", created_at: "2013-02-14 12:13:53", updated_at: "2013-02-14 12:13:53", slug: "test1-20130214-another-post", forum_id: 1> 
1.9.3p194 :010 > p.created_at
 => Thu, 14 Feb 2013 12:13:53 UTC +00:00
```

As you can see, the created_at timestamp is saved as per lunchtime on the 14th, and flagged as being that time *IN UTC*.  What I actually want is for it to look at the local time, be aware that I'm in Melbourne, and convert to UTC by (in this case) subtracting 11 hours.

Now, I know I can edit these lines in my config/application.rb:

```
config.time_zone = 'UTC'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'UTC'
```

(I think changing config.time_zone to 'Australia/Melbourne' would fix it? Probably?)

However, if I change any of that to "Australia/Melbourne" (or whatever), then what happens to our deployed app (on Heroku), and my co-developers in Maryland and Oregon and Glasgow?  Do we all have to set our times individually?  Should we do it via environment variables, perhaps?  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

OK, so it looks like this fixes it for us:

```
config.time_zone = 'UTC'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

We're a little dubious and will wait and see how it goes when we deploy and/or run our test suite in everyone's timezones, but for now it seems like it works... in Melbourne at least ;)

Comment: You can set the timezone in your Postgres database as well, but I believe your app still needs the configs you used above